# What is the first/last week of a month?

Tags: date, definition

If someone were to say something happens in the first or last week of some month, how would you define that span?

---

### Background

I'm working on a library that needs to handle this kind of thing in an intuitive way, but my intuition doesn't claim one case or the other.

I can make it select different behavior but still need a good default.

---

For a concrete example I'll just to pick an random month: July 2008

```
s  m  t  w  r  f  s
--------------------
      1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
```

*(Note: I'll assume the week starts with Sunday but the question could be asked re Monday as well)*

What span is the first week of the month?

1. June 29 - July 5 *-- the week that includes the first*
2. July 6 - 12 *-- the first week that is all the way into the month*

The second week is just the 7 days following the first right?

What span is the last week of the month?

1. July 27 - Aug 2 *-- ditto but the last day*
2. July 20 - 26 *-- ditto but the last week*

*Non wiki comments welcome*

Comment: If you're expecting wiki answers, make it a wiki question.  Otherwise it appears to be a game for reputation. Also, why aren't you using a readily available library?

Comment: I'm building a date parser and didn't find anything that did a good enough job.

Comment: I'm not looking for wiki answers. The one's I'm adding are just for voting.

Comment: You should make your question a CW as well

Comment: @TheTXI: Why? (I'm curious, not being defensive)

Comment: @BCS: It's a poll. That's why.

Comment: @TheTXI: the answers are. the question its self is a legit question.

Comment: @Gortok, the simple fact it's a poll indicates it's subjective. If it wasn't subjective then you couldn't have a poll (or if you did, everyone would vote for the same option)

Comment: BCS: Poll questions are discouraged: You'd be better served making it a CW to mitigate chances it'll be closed.

Comment: @malfist: 600 years ago, if you took a poll to see whether the earth was round or flat, you'd get different answers.  That wasn't subjective, and neither is this.

Comment: @Gortok: Are you saying there is a correct answer?

Comment: @TheTXI: Yes, the Earth is round.  Can we move on now? :-D

Comment: @Gortok as they understood it, yes, it would have been a subjective answer.

Comment: @Malfist: subjectivity - judgment based on individual personal impressions and feelings and opinions rather than external facts. You don't feel whether or not the earth is round. If you think it's flat, its not a subjective opinion, its a false belief.

Comment: But this isn't about a set fact, it's subjective because there is no real definition

Answer (score 15):

[There is no answer because it varies even inside a country.](http://www.linguistlist.org/issues/12/12-1858.html)

However, [this source](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=484347) seems to think it's defined by the ISO standard as the first week that contains a thursday. However the above source says that the ISO standard does not list a specification for 'first week of the month'

---

*More than 300 chars - sorry!*

The ISO 8601 standard defines the first week of the YEAR as:

> calendar week number
>
> ordinal number which identifies a calendar week within its calendar year according to the rule that the first
> calendar week of a year is that one which includes the first Thursday of that year and that the last calendar
> week of a calendar year is the week immediately preceding the first calendar week of the next calendar year

There is nothing in ISO 8601 about the first week of the month because, as has been noted, the definition varies by country (and even by company, for example).  Oh, and the standard says that weeks start on Monday.

Comment: OK I sort of figured that was the real answer. Now what would you /like/ it to be?

Comment: This won't help in the development of a date parsing library.

Comment: "There is nothing in ISO 8601 about the first week of the month" - While that might be true, it is by implication that the 1st week of a month must follow the same ISO rules as the 1st week of the year. Anything else would likely lead to the absurd situation where the 1st week of the year is not the 1st week in January (in one and the same standard).  
  
(Yep, it seems 10 years later this is still an unclarified issue. :))

Answer (score 6):

If you are building a library, you should allow the user to choose how they want to handle it either by having methods that return the first/last full/partial week of the month or by passing an argument that indicates whether you want the full/partial week.  Clearly document whichever is the default if you provide methods that don't require the specification.

```
public Week GetFirstFullWeekOfMonth( DateTime forDate ) { }

public Week GetFirstPartialWeekOfMonth( DateTime forDate ) { }
```

Or

```
public Week GetFirstWeekOfMonth( DateTime forDate, bool includePartial ) {}
```

Comment: Noted. Now what default should I use?

Comment: I would probably default to the first/last full week and allow the user to choose if they want partial weeks.

Answer (score 4):

The first week of the month is the week that includes the first

1. June 29 - July 5

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted... this is the definition I've always used.  All the other interpretations don't make any sense to me.

Comment: You can use this as long as the last week of the month is the last week wholly contained within the month; otherwise, you get gaps - weeks not belonging to either month.

Answer (score 3):

The first week of the month is the first week that is all the way int the month

2. July 6 - 12

Comment: This coupled with the 'last week of the month is the last week that is all the way in the month' leaves a gap of 1 week unowned by either month most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

The last week of the month is the week that includes the last day

1. July 27 - Aug 2

Comment: If you couple this definition with 'first week of the month is the week that includes the first of the month', you get some weeks belong to two months at the same time.  You need to define both the first and the last week rules in pairs, making sure they don't overlap.

Comment: The 5th week of the month (if any) will always push into the next month. *I* don't mind having some weeks have more than one name. Do you see any reason to avoid it?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on why you're calling it the last week of the month.  Accountants tend to get upset if you try counting the revenue earned in the last week of July and the first week of August and end up double-counting the revenue.

Comment: Similarly, people would get upset if they took one week's vacation and because it is both the last week of July and the first week of August, the company dings them for 10 days vacation time when they only took 5 days off work.

Comment: I'm looking for a map /to/ a date span; "last week"->date-date, not from it.

Answer (score 2):

The last week of the month is the last week that is all the way int the month

2. July 20 - 26

Comment: This makes sense when coupled with 'first week is the week that includes the first of the month'.

Answer (score 2):

The first week of the month is week 0 - the week that has the first day of the month.
The last week is the week with the last day of the month

Hence the weeknumber of the last week of july IS THE SAME as the weeknumber of the first week of august

** UNLESS **

the month in question ends on the last day of the last week, in wich case the following month would start on the first day of the new week and have a different weeknumber

:)

Answer (score 1):

My definition would be the first week is the week of the first working day in the month, 
and likewise the last week is the week of the last working day in the month.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that one... Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

The first week of the month is the first week that owns 4 or more days of the defined week period. (Not really but I thought I'd throw it in as an option)

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly obvious option you are missing.  The first week of the month is the seven days starting with the first day of the month.  Hence, in your example, the first week would be Tuesday, the 1st through Monday, the 7th.  This way, the first through 4th weeks would always be fully contained within the month, and only the 5th week would cross over.

Comment: I had thought of that one but rejected it as a useless option: Who would use that option and where? After being correct+relevant, I'd rather be incorrect+relevant before being correct+irrelevant.

Comment: I don't know what your library is going to be used for, so I don't know what is relevant and what isn't.  Merely pointing out that there was a third option.